# TAUCS library cannot find -lg2c: where to download g2c.a from

Tags: linker, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to install "TAUCS" (http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/) library. However, I am getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test: Command not found
```

and more errors follow.

I guess that the main error is not being able to find lg2c.

I guess I use already `gcc` which uses `gfortran` instead of `g77`. Where can I find `g2c.a`?

Searching in software manager returns me with no result. Searching in google gives me everything else other than what I am looking for.

UPDATE:
I could install g77 as described.

```
However, that still leaves an error:
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h


C99 complex numbers seem to be supported, 1+sqrt(-1)=-1.000000+1.000000i


cc -c -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_cilk_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o
progs/taucs_cilk_test.c:8:19: fatal error: cilk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cilk.h> 
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
cc   \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_cilk_test \
      obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o -L external/lib/linux -llapack -L external/lib/linux -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -L external/lib/linux -lmetis  -lg2c   -lm 
cc: error: obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o: No such file or directory
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
cc -c -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
    -DTAUCS_CORE_GENERAL \
    src/taucs_sn_llt.c \
    -oobj/linux/taucs_sn_llt.o
src/taucs_sn_llt.c:1339:1: error: ‘tree_first_descendant’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
 tree_first_descendant(int j,
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [obj/linux/taucs_sn_llt.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to install TAUCS library

1) Download the Version 2.2 of the code, with external libraries, tgz format

```
wget http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/2.2/taucs_full.tgz
```

2) Unpack it in your chosen location

```
mkdir taucs_full

tar xvf taucs_full.tgz -C taucs_full

cd taucs_full
```

3)If you didn't already do so, install libf2c2-dev (for libf2c)

```
sudo apt-get install libf2c2-dev
```

4) Remove the -Werror flag from the global compiler options file (there are going to be warnings, so it will never build if we treat them as errors)

```
sed -i 's/-Werror//g' config/linux.mk
```

5)Now run the configure script

```
./configure
```

6) Finally we need to do some command and library wrangling for the actual make

```
make "CC=gcc" "FC=gfortran" "LIBF77=-Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran"
```

You should get a binary executable in ./bin/linux - If you just try to run,  it will give this message:

```
$ bin/linux/taucs_run 
taucs_run: there is no matrix!
```

The credit for this answer must go to @steeldriver from [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576127/how-to-install-library-that-uses-g77)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing g77.

I did the following:
1) Downloaded g77 for 64 bits from here
http://www.ziddu.com/download/16792814/g77_x64_debian_and_ubuntu.tar.gz.html

You can choose 32 bits accordingly.

2) Then did the following:

```
tar -xzvf g77_x64_debian_and_ubuntu.tar.gz
cd  g77_x64_debian_and_ubuntu
chmod +x ./install.sh
./install.sh
```

(answer adapted from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346278/really-need-g77-on-ubuntu-12-04-cant-install))

Comment: Yes, it removed error regarding "cannot find -lg2c". But, error with "cannot find -lmetis" is still there. I am updating my question accordingly.

Comment: @GarimaSingh Obviously, install also metis.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks. What about skipping incompatible libraries? I have decribed my problem in other post of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070755/gcc-skipping-incompatible-libraries-lapack-blas-atlas-metis

Comment: @GarimaSingh Seems like 32bit vs 64 bit issue. I would suggest you to change the Makefile and forget g77.